# Why a computed field is not accesible from a TransientModel in Odoo8?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-8

**ENVIRONMENT**

I have created two `TransientModel` (named `lots.manager` and `product.lot.available`), with a `One2many` relationship between them (a lot manager will have several available lots).

My purpose is to show a list of the available lots, and the user will be able to select which lots he wants to use and how much quantity from each one. So `product.lot.available` have the fields `lot_id` (to select a lot), `selected` (a `Boolean` which indicates if the lot is used or not), and `qty` (a `Float` which indicates the quantity used from each lot).

On the other side, in `lots.manager` model, I have a computed field named `total_qty_selected`, which calculates the sum of the `qty` of all the available lots whose `selected` field is *True*.

**CODE**

```
class LotsManager(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'lots.manager'

    @api.multi
    @api.depends('product_lots_available', 'product_lots_available.selected',
                 'product_lots_available.qty')
    def _compute_total_qty_selected(self):
        for manager in self:
            total = 0
            for lot in manager.product_lots_available:
                if lot.selected is True:
                    total += lot.qty
            manager.total_qty_selected = total

    move_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='stock.move',
        string='Stock move',
        required=True,
        select=True,
        readonly=True,
    )
    product_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='product.product',
        related='move_id.product_id',
        string='Product',
    )
    product_lots_available = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='product.lot.available',
        inverse_name='manager_id',
        string='Available lots',
    )
    total_qty_selected = fields.Float(
        compute='_compute_total_qty_selected',
        string='Total quantity selected',
    )


class ProductLotAvailable(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'product.lot.available'

    manager_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='lots.manager',
        string='Lots Manager',
    )
    lot_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='stock.production.lot',
        string='Lot',
        readonly=True,
    )
    selected = fields.Boolean(
        string='Selected',
        default=False,
    )
    qty = fields.Float(
        string='Quantity',
        default=0.00,
    )

    @api.onchange('selected')
    def onchange_selected(self):
        if self.selected is True:
            _logger.info(self.manager_id.product_id.name)
            _logger.info(self.manager_id.total_qty_selected)
```

**PROBLEM**

The computed field `total_qty_selected` is calculated well (I show it in the views and works great), but, when I try to read it from `product.lot.available` I always get 0. For example, the `_logger` lines in the `onchange` function above, show me the name of the product right, but the `total_qty_selected` returns 0, instead of in that moment I can read 2.00 in the form, or whatever value different from 0.

I need to get the right value for doing some stuff in the onchange function.

Can anyone help me how to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `store=True` in your computed field. Try below code

```
class LotsManager(models.TransientModel):
_name = 'lots.manager'

   total_qty_selected = fields.Float(
    compute='_compute_total_qty_selected',
    string='Total quantity selected', store=True
)
```

Comment: I tried, just in case, but same result with `store=True`. I guess that setting `store=True` a field of a `TransientModel` does not make much sense, because the records of that kind of models will not be stored.

Comment: Then try class class_name(models.Model)

Comment: It must be a `TransientModel`, because it is a specific form to select some values and apply some actions, but not for storing new records.

Comment: I think, to access a values you have to store it. Other wise (worst case), bring all fields of in single form view, then you can access total_qty_selected in on_change method, i don't know it suits your requirement.

Comment: @forvas `store=True` makes sense on a TransientModel. Odoo really creates a table in database for this model. It's only ephemeral because records of that table are deleted when expired. See `_transient_vacuum` in `odoo/models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to solve this problem, with a horrible workaround. But it works well.

I added the following field to `lots.manager` model:

```
total_qty_selected_copy = fields.Float(
    string='Total quantity selected (copy)',
    default=False,
)
```

And this field changes every time the original one does, adding this code:

```
@api.one
@api.onchange('total_qty_selected')
def onchange_selected(self):
    self.total_qty_selected_copy = self.total_qty_selected
```

Obviously, I had to add `total_qty_selected_copy` to the XML view, and I made it invisible.

After those modifications, I can get the value I need from `product.lot.available` model through this new field:

```
@api.onchange('selected')
def onchange_selected(self):
    if self.selected is True:
        _logger.info(self.manager_id.product_id.name)
        _logger.info(self.manager_id.total_qty_selected_copy)
```